# XO of a naval cruiser leads an internal investigation

Tags: internal-consistency, spaceships, death, space-warfare, navy

In a future space navy setup, a Long Duration Mission cruiser experiences a mysterious death while in deep space. A member of the crew mysteriously dies while at their station and causes a series of events that lead to several deaths on board.

Fearing the crew member might have been poisoned or infected with something, but he he CO starts an investigation to try to solve this, especially once a few other crew members are found dead with similar traits. The ship is quarantined and no one is allowed on or off.

I believe it is typical that the XO is responsible for many of the day to day dealings aboard the ship, so they tend to interact with the crew more. With that thought,
**is it plausible that the XO would lead an investigation into the death of a crew member at seas(stars)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to take a look a the Uniform Code of Military Justice, and Non Judicial Punishment (NJP)which is know as "Captains Mast" in the Navy and the different types of court martial Summary, Special and General. Each type of court martial would have different requirements with a General being the most serious. A summary court martial doesn't require a military judge and can only be done by one officer - but is only for minor offenses. A General Court Martial would need a Military Judge as well a panel of 10 members (usually officers, although up to a certain number enlisted can be requested).

Usually a service member can turn down NJP and request a court martial, but there is a Naval Vessel exception, where a Captain can force it to be Captains mast (NJP) instead. Before having a general court-martial there needs to be a formal investigation. Court marital are rarely performed at sea. However doing an investigation, interviewing, collecting evidence etc. can certainly be performed at sea.

So what can you Captain do?

Certainly hold an investigation.  How open about letting the crew know that an investigation is being done is probably a judgement call.  But he would certainly document what he is doing, and set up some way to protect and preserve any evidence with some type of chain of custody. Having the XO be assigned to do the investigation is probably the right call, especially since the XO before taking his assignment would have had some training in UCMJ and procedures. The CO before taking command also would have training in judicial procedures.

So let's say they find something, or they have suspicions of some bad actors. The need to do something, but a General Court Martial may not be feasible. The CO isn't a military judge.

However, the CO and XO  can do a lot of things such as confine a person to their quarters. Or if there is a brig, put them in the brig. Or confine them to a portion of the ship, so they can still stand their watch, but keep them away from critical equipment. The CO and XO can also do things like require them to be guarded or be escorted at all times. They can require a buddy system, a two person rule, or have the galley guarded to prevent further poisoning. You could have the guards have small arms, but that would really be unusual.

To do those kinds of things and keep things above board the CO might choose for there to be a NJP process, and have that process in the presence of other officers. That would give the accused an opportunity to give their side of the story and also have some representation. Or depending on the situation might not have a NJP and just give them a set of orders, but doing something formally and documenting it might prevent problems later. It also keeps the rumor mill down and keeps the crew informed.

The various rules can also be different somewhat when "war" is formally declared.

Liberty (getting on and off the ship) is normally controlled anyway. You always want to have enough crew to get the ship underway. The senior enlisted and division officers, may be controlling it so they have people to do maintenance or other tasks. Before landing in port, an in-port watch schedule would be posted and it would be pretty clear who is allowed on or off the ship usually by watch section. The XO and Department heads usually review the watch schedules, reports would be given to the ships in port duty officer for him to decide when to announce liberty. The CO or sometimes the XO can cancel liberty any time, or do an emergency recall to have people come back to the ship. Cancelling Liberty doesn't make you popular...

If there is some local authority, the CO could look into removing people from the ship and putting them into the custody of others. Of course that assumes there is someone to hand them off to. It probably isn't ethical or legal to turn them over to aliens or representative of another government.

If communications are possible in your story, the CO and XO, would be burning the ether to have communications with higher authority, depending on the situation.  If there are not communications, it is back to the CO having to make good decisions on his own and carrying out his mission the best way he can (in some cases hopefully with some advice from the XO and other senior officers).

This is from a US Navy perspective, you of course could look into how other countries do things, or have your own take. A big ship would be different than a small ship with a smaller crew.

Answer (score 3):

**Potentially plausible**

A CO who is out of contact with higher authority basically has to make any and all decisions independently.  There are some decisions / actions that the CO may be legislatively prevented from taking (eg summary execution of crew members without due process, unless it's the [Dread Empire's Fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dread_Empire%27s_Fall) universe, in which case that's valid too).  Otherwise, the CO will follow Standard Operating Procedures for most situations but will use their judgement for everything else.

However, note that most ships with a sufficiently large crew will have a master-at-arms (the exact title may vary), who may have experience at investigations - think [NCIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCIS_(TV_series)) (TV series) without the gratuitous gun battles and explosions.  A warship on extended independent operations will almost certainly have a surgeon, who might be the obvious person to lead a purely medical investigation.  So additional background or circumstances may be required in order for the XO to be put in charge of the investigation, especially since it is likely to detract from him conducting his normal duties, which have probably become less routine due to the follow-on effects of the deaths.  Possibly the master-at-arms was one of the casualties or is otherwise incapacitated and the XO has served as an investigator previously.

In short, some justification may be required to make the XO the sensible choice to conduct an investigation, but it is not inherently implausible.

Comment: I would call it quite plausible if the CO either does have a ship to command, or expects to become the *judge* in a court martial. Make the XO both the investigator and the prosecutor once they have a suspect, keep another qualified officer in reserve to become the defense counsel.

Comment: Good point re the CO potentially sitting as judge, although some military codes will forbid or strongly discourage having the same person as investigator and prosecutor.  It is also preferable, though not essential, for both prosecutor and defender to be the same rank to make it clear it is an equal playing field, putting the XO in as prosecutor puts the inevitably more junior defending officer at a disadvantage.  Eg in Australian Army subordinate summary authority proceedings I have been part of, typically prosecutor and defender would both be LT or both be SGT.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you that the ships such as cruisers have a Command Master at Arms (CMA) who is responsible for investigations, collecting statements and evidence which are brought before the chief’s mess where they grill those involved for more info, then it could go up to XOI (executive officer’s inquiry), and after that, if it is warranted, it can be recommended for captain’s mast, which can either be closed (a private hearing, with only the sailor, the CMA, and the chain of command of the accused, and witnesses) or open, the sailor in question brought before the CO in front of the entire crew (this is very rare and I’ve only heard of a few of these). If you are looking for some sort of a detective, I’d use the role of the CMA, which could be very interesting. I hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome CapnKidd. Please enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when.

Answer (score 0):

While the XO does interact more with the crew than the CO, there are still *several* layers between them and the average member of the crew. Also, there would already be systems and teams in place for things like this. It is commonplace for larger-crewed vessels to have an NCIS agent aboard as well as a devoted Special Investigations Unit.

As a comparison, the XO is the *overall* manager of the ship's maintenance system, but they're not turning wrenches.

That being said, there's nothing stopping the XO from taking a personal interest in the investigation -- especially if they have a background in security or criminal justice.